# API Яндекс карт

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Вытащил из файлов фотографий gps координаты. Расставил метки Placemark
на карте. Подскажите как получить название населённого пункта, имея только координаты?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Обратное геокодирование, https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/geocoder/doc/desc/concepts/about.html

Comment: Спасибо,  another_login )

Comment: Реализовал на php  : 
 <?php
 $yandex_maps_geocode = file_get_contents("https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?format=json&apikey=Мой_Ключ&geocode=".$v[3].",".$v[2]);
 $yandex_maps_geocode = json_decode($yandex_maps_geocode);
 $locality_name = ($yandex_maps_geocode->response->GeoObjectCollection->featureMember[0]->GeoObject->metaDataProperty->GeocoderMetaData->text);
 ?>